# I am trying to install ofbiz behind a web server by using mod_proxy_ajp but I cannot get it to work

Tags: apache, tomcat, ofbiz

I am trying to use https://mydomain.ltd/ofbiz/.... format

Apache server setup

```
ProxyPass "/ofbiz" "ajp://10.90.0.100:8009"
ProxyPassReverse "/ofbiz" "ajp://10.90.0.100:8009"
```

This is ajp-connector setup

```
<property name="ajp-connector" value="connector">
            <!-- see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/ajp.html for reference -->
            <property name="address" value="10.90.0.100"/>
            <property name="port" value="8009"/>
            <property name="protocol" value="AJP/1.3"/>
            <property name="scheme" value="https"/>
            <property name="secure" value="true"/>
            <property name="URIEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="xpoweredBy" value="false"/>
            <property name="secretRequired" value="false"/>
            <property name="allowedRequestAttributesPattern" value=".*"/> 
        </property>
```

in url.properties I have set `content.url.prefix.secure=/ofbiz` so that I can get contents to work like `/ofbiz/common/...`. But the problem is all other links has not prefix. They are like `/accounting/control/login` but ther should have prefix like `/ofbiz/accounting/control/login`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If your AJP connection works, trying using

```
content.url.prefix.secure=https://10.90.0.100
content.url.prefix.standard=https://10.90.0.100
```

Comment: Thank you I will try and inform here